# Setting up an auto email mechanism in SVN

Tags: svn, version

How can I set up a mechanism for SVN where in the team automatically gets email whenever a commit is made to SVN repository.

thanks
kabir...

Comment: Wow, 18 questions and no answers accepted.

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported natively by `SVN`, so far as I know, but you can use an external program and implement repository hooks to get the job done. Google for `SVN Post-Commit Hook`.

Or, more specifically, check out this link: [Using Subversion Hooks to send out build emails](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/244.cfm).

As a side note, the results you achieve will be *automatic*, but getting to that point certainly won't be, be prepared to plan this into your development time - at least for the first project you attempt it with.

Answer (score 0):

Is this is not an overkill? But anyways the easiest way is to write a hook.See this [link](https://docs.rice.edu/confluence/display/ITPUB/Subversion+Hook+commit-email) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a post commit hook that sends emails. You could assign emails addresses to folders/projects using svn properties to limit the mail noise to subscribers. For instance we have a property called mailto which is a comma separated list of email recipients. The post commit hook script walks through the folder tree, get's this property, builds a unique mailing list and sends the mails.